# Is there a way I can connect my web app to Quickbooks desktop using Javascript/NodeJS?

Tags: node.js, quickbooks

I'm trying to connect my web app to Quickbooks Desktop (*not Quickbooks Online*). My web app is developed using Nodejs and Angular . I already connected my web app with Quickbooks Online using *node-quickbooks* library.

In Quickbooks documentation, they did not mention anything about connecting the web app to Quickbooks Desktop using NodeJS.

Answer (score 1):

Connection to quickbooks desktop is done through the Quickbooks Web Connector, the docs for which can be found here;
https://developer.intuit.com/app/developer/qbdesktop/docs/get-started/get-started-with-quickbooks-web-connector

Comment: And to expand on that a little further - the Web Connector talks a relatively simple set of SOAP commands. You'll probably end up with something like https://github.com/vpulim/node-soap to implement the protocol.